# Removing window decorations of gnome terminal in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, 19.04

So I've tried this a lot of ways already and none seems to work on the newer version. 
Is there a way to remove the window decorations from terminal? Because they are literally of no use and only look weird.

Answer (score 1):

Making it on full-screen mode (F11) may be a workaround for this need

Answer (score 0):

Open `dconf-editor`, navigate to `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/headerbar` and change it to `False` to switch back to the previous look (which still has some decoration, provided by your window manager).

You need to restart gnome-terminal (quit all its windows at once) for the change to take effect.

Comment: Ahh I wanted the top bar gone all together, this just removes a couple of buttons.

Comment: Don't you want to do it for all your windows, then (not just the terminal)? I'm sure there are window managers that can do it if you disable headerbar, although I'm sorry I'm not aware of concrete details.

Comment: Yeah I can use a dwm but I do use gnome sometimes and on gnome it's only the terminal that has the most redundant window decorations. I don't remember ever looking at it and being oh wow this is a lot of useful information. It just looks ugly. So

Comment: I don't think GNOME is a platform that offers these kinds of tweaks. Maybe you can find an extension, I don't know. Or alter gnome-terminal's source. (I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question that you wanted to get back to Ubuntu 18.10's behavior.)

Comment: pixelsaver used to, but it doesn't seem to work as well in debian11 and gnome-3.38